# How/When do I unbind the event handlers

Tags: inheritance, xamarin.forms, event-binding

In my application I inherit most of the Xamarin controls so that I can extent some functionality. However I am not sure how I should be removing the event handlers as there are not dispose methods. Below is a sample of what I have. I am binding to the TextChanged event but not sure when to unbind

```
public class SBMNumericEntry : Entry
{
    public SBMNumericEntry()
    {
        HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.End;
        Keyboard = Keyboard.Numeric;

        TextChanged += SBMNumericEntry_TextChanged;
    }

    private void SBMNumericEntry_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //SOME CUSTOM LOGIC HERE
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this particular case, you don't have to unhook the eventhandler, it won't prevent garbage collection